# Mongoose array indexOf not working as it should

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I've got a document in mongoose which looks like this:

```
{  
  "_id":ObjectId("553e4d7a1ebb424364e47e0f"),
  "url":"/api/images/553e4d6f1ebb424364e47e0b",
  "type":"knowledge",
  "title":"asdasd",
  "week":18,
  "fields":{  
    "end":"sdajlsdjlfnsdf",
    "correctAnswer":"2",
    "answers":{  
      "0":"ljnsdlfjnsdfn",
      "1":"lnsldfnlsf",
      "2":"ljsndlfnsdlf"
    },
    "question":"sjlnasjld"
  },
  "participants":[  
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e4d531ebb424364e47e07"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e4e3bb4ad1bbb646a545c"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e4ecc007b12e464c6a7ff"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"1"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e4ecc007b12e464c6a7ff"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e5239b1d44ec7681bcb66"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e52be4d85843e69828df3"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e52cd8dded86469ee3974"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e537b6c4981b169a10c3d"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e5553afb1fd6e6a90e6af"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e55ddda5144976aa90224"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e563af09b82e46ac30c0c"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e563af09b82e46ac30c0c"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e563af09b82e46ac30c0c"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e57b6d554ab136caa95a8"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    },
    {  
      "user":ObjectId("553e5a7c094e51826d88dbff"),
      "result":{  
        "answer":"2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is to restrict 'participants' from participating in the mission if they've already completed it. I'm using this code to try to restrict them but it's not working as it should:

```
if (mission.participants && mission.participants.map(function (e) { return e.user; }).indexOf(uid) > -1) {
  return res.send(403, { err: "You've already completed this mission" });
}
```

No matter what I try the `indexOf` function always returns `-1`

If I run `console.log(mission.participants.map(function (e) { return e.user; }));` I get

```
[ 553e4d531ebb424364e47e07,
  553e4e3bb4ad1bbb646a545c,
  553e4ecc007b12e464c6a7ff,
  553e4ecc007b12e464c6a7ff,
  553e5239b1d44ec7681bcb66,
  553e52be4d85843e69828df3,
  553e52cd8dded86469ee3974,
  553e537b6c4981b169a10c3d,
  553e5553afb1fd6e6a90e6af,
  553e55ddda5144976aa90224,
  553e563af09b82e46ac30c0c,
  553e563af09b82e46ac30c0c,
  553e563af09b82e46ac30c0c,
  553e57b6d554ab136caa95a8,
  553e5a7c094e51826d88dbff ]
```

I have verified that the `uid` variable is actually in the array, so that's not the issue.

Running `io.js v1.8.1`, `mongoose v4.0.1`, `MongoDB v2.6.9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing an object `Schema#ObjectId` to a `String`. You need to convert the ObjectId to String in your map function, so the `indexOf` can find the desired `uid`:

```
if (mission.participants && mission.participants.map(function (e) { return e.user.toString(); }).indexOf(uid) > -1) {
  return res.send(403, { err: "You've already completed this mission" });
}
```

Comment: Sorry victorkohl for not getting back to you until now. This makes sense, and I tried convert the ObjectId to a String with the toString method, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `uid.toString()` in the `indexOf` method. Odd though, as the `uid` is attached to `req.user._id` directly from a mongo document in an express middleware I wrote, so the `uid` should be a `Schema#ObjectId` as well.